# How to copy element from ng repeat scope to outside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am pretty new to angularjs, and I have spent quite a lot of time on finding the solution but can't find anything.

basically, I have a form to add new fields, and there is a list to show all the new fields added at the bottom using ng-repeat. when I click on edit button on the list item, it will then copy all values to the top form, and you can click "update" button to push new value set to the list below.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I can't get it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/floracqx/c6m2S/7/

```
$scope.edit = function(item, index) {


        $scope.Title = item.title;
        $scope.Location = item.location;

        $scope.Editing = true;



        return false;

    };

    $scope.update = function(item, index) {

        item.title = $scope.Title;
        item.location = $scope.Location;

        $scope.stepEditing = false;

    }
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you missed the "Edit" button. In your demo I just see the add and update buttons.

Comment: edit button is as an icon, I just updated it as link, please check now.

Comment: The fiddle seems to do what your question says it should do. What's the problem?

Comment: my problem is updating, I want "Add" button to be "Update" button, when edit button on the list is clicked. So I don't need to click "update" button in the bottom list, but use "Update" button in the top form and it will apply the value set back to the list below. I like to use form in top when doing editing, not through "Update" button in the bottom list. Does it make sense? I know it seems a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the edit function at all. You can also overwrite the ngModel of title and location with ng-click. Please note that I changed `$scope.Title' to`$scope.myForm.title' and `$scope.Location' to`$scope.myForm.location' for better readability.

The JS will then look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $compile) {

    // adding new item
    var items = $scope.items = [];

    $scope.add = function() {

        var newItemObj = {

            title: $scope.myForm.title,
            location: $scope.myForm.location
        };

        items.push(newItemObj);

    };

    $scope.update = function(item, index){

        item.title      = $scope.myForm.title;
        item.location   = $scope.myForm.location;

        $scope.stepEditing = false;

    }

});
```

The overwrite function for "Edit" looks like this in the HTML:

```
<a ng-click="myForm.title = item.title; myForm.location = item.location" href="#">
Edit
</a>
```

I updated the jsfiddle so you can try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/c6m2S/4/

**Update, after the comment:**

If you just want one Update button, the first thing is to change $scope.items to an array. We need to do this, because the array has an index, which we can remember and overwrite the item on the index. The JSON object, which you currently use, doesn't use indexes. You could still force such a behaviour by using id or index attributes in JSON to mark an object in the JSON.

Anyway, the following example is using an array:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ItemController', function ($scope, $compile) {

    // array for the itmes
    $scope.items = [];

    // the object for the form fields
    $scope.myForm = {};

    // label for the button
    $scope.myForm.buttonlabel = "Add";

    // this marks the currentItem, if the user clicks on edit
    $scope.myForm.currentItem = undefined;

    //use array here, so index can be used
    $scope.add = function () {
        if ($scope.myForm.currentItem !== undefined) {
            $scope.items[$scope.myForm.currentItem][0] = $scope.myForm.title;
            $scope.items[$scope.myForm.currentItem][1] = $scope.myForm.location;
            $scope.myForm.currentItem = undefined;
            $scope.myForm.buttonlabel = "Add";
        } else {
            $scope.items.push([$scope.myForm.title, $scope.myForm.location]);
        }
    };

});
```

The variable `$scope.myForm.currentItem' will remember the index of the current item, if the user clicks edit. The`add()' function now handles both `add' and`update'. When a currentItem is marked, it will overwrite the item, if not, it will add a new item. The label of the button is saved to `$scope.myForm.buttonlabel'. After editing an item, the button will change to`Update', if not, it will stay `Add'.

The HTML needs to change according to the use of arrays instead of JSON. Furthermore, ng-click on the edit button also saves the current `$index' to`$scope.myForm.currentItem'.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="container" id="new" ng-controller="ItemController">

        <div ng-class="{editing: Editing}" id="Form">
            <h2>new:</h2>

            <div class="inputfield">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true" ng-model="myForm.title"/>
            </div>

            <div class="inputfield">
                <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Location" ng-required="true" ng-model="myForm.location"/>
            </div>


            <div class="inputfield">
                <a href="#" class="button addBtn" ng-click="add()">{{myForm.buttonlabel}}</a>
            </div>

            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">

                    <div class="list">

                        <div class="view title">
                            <span>{{item[0]}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="view">
                            <span>{{item[1]}}</span>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <a ng-click="myForm.title = item[0]; myForm.location = item[1]; myForm.currentItem = $index; myForm.buttonlabel = 'Update'" href="#">
                    Edit
                    </a>


                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I updated the jsfiddle, so you may see and test it: http://jsfiddle.net/c6m2S/9/

Comment: thanks for answering so quick. I didn't make my question clear earlier. I like to add an update button in the form section, so when I click on the edit button on the list, I can use "Update" button in the top form to update, not the one that's tied with the list item.

Comment: I updated the answer regarding your comment you posted on the answer and the comment you posted on your question.